# How to send a GET request but from a different location?

Tags: java, get, connection, ip

This is my code which **works** on my PC:

```java
try(BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new URL("...").openStream())))
{
    reader.lines().forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

But returns 403 for my friend who lives abroad. I checked and the problem is that the website allows requests only from my country.

Is there a way to bypass this except for forcing my friend to use a VPN? I obviously want my program to work out of the box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on how the website determines your friend is not "in" the right country.  The most likely method is by inspecting the IP address of your friend's machine and then looking this up in a geo-location database.

If this is the method that the site uses, there is no way around that except for your friend to appear to come from an "ok" country.  It seems you are in an "ok" country... or rather your external IP address is acceptable to the server.  You could therefore open up a proxy for your friend.  Your friend makes the request to your machine which then proxies onwards.  This is one of the features of a VPN.

Comment: Can I change anything in the request in order to appear from another country? I tried googling but couldn't find anything. I don't want my friend(or anyone else) to use VPN, I want my program to work out of the box.

Comment: If the server is guessing location by looking at the IP address of the caller, there is nothing you can do to change the request

Comment: I'm not an expert in web programming, isn't there a way to modify the IP in the request?

Comment: A web request goes FROM an IP address TO an IP address.  The FROM address is mentioned in the Packet of data sent to the other computer.  This address is used to send back the response.  So even if you managed to change the FROM address then you would not receive the response.  For this reason you cannot modify the FROM address!